# Invalid map literal with Cassandra Query

Tags: collections, cassandra

I'm trying to do this query :

`insert into test (id, identifiers) values('1', {'id':'test', 'id_bin':{'\x3500000000000050a0'}, 'oidcatref':'1', 'otype_bin':'1', 'id_qaul':'test', 'id_flag':'1'});`

That's my identifier type :

`create type identifier(id text, id_bin list<blob>, oidcatref bigint, otype_bin int, id_qaul text, id_flag smallint);`

And my table structure :

`create table test (id int primary key, identifiers frozen<identifier>);`

I really don't know what is wrong, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

**Only enclose string value with single quote. And for UDT field remove quote from field name**

```
insert into test (id, identifiers) values 
(
   1,
   { 
       id     :'test', 
       id_bin : [0x3500000000000050a0], 
       oidcatref : 1, 
       otype_bin : 1, 
       id_qaul : 'test', 
       id_flag : 1
    }
);
```